# Concatenate columns of dataframes in a loop Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of csv files with two columns: wavelengths and absorbance values.

I'd like to do some statistical analysis within a loop, which contains a set of files, e.g. a mean absorbance file with standard deviation etc.

```
myfiles = sorted(glob.glob('blanks/Day01/Batch02/*.csv'))
mypath = 'blanks/Day01/Batch02/'
files         = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]   # all files in a folder

for m in range(len(files)):
    df = pd.read_csv(mypath + files[m], skiprows=1, delimiter= ',')
    wl = df['Wavelength (nm)']
    A  = df['Abs']
```

My question is how do I "concatenate" 'Abs' columns from each file and then operate on them creating one single, mean/median one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create list of all DataFrames - filter columns by parameter `usecols` in `read_csv` and also is possible omit `delimiter=','` because default parameter:

```
dfs = []
for m in range(len(files)):
    df = pd.read_csv(mypath + files[m], 
                     skiprows=1, 
                     usecols = ['Wavelength (nm)', 'Abs']) # usecols = ['Abs'] for filter Abs
    dfs.append(df)
```

Alternative:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(mypath + files[m], skiprows=1, usecols = ['Wavelength (nm)', 'Abs']) for m in range(len(files))]
```

And last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! What about the creation of a mean "ABS" column based on the same wavelength values, should one use groupby?

Comment: @PEBKAC - Yes, exactly. Need `df.groupby('Wavelength (nm)', as_index=False)['Abs'].mean()`

Comment: and if need mean and median - `df.groupby('Wavelength (nm)', as_index=False)['Abs'].agg(['mean','median'])`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was extremely helpful! ;-)